# Disable pinch to zoom is not working using iPhone onto my React Application

Tags: javascript, iphone, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, pinchzoom

into my application I've disabled pinch to zoom using those lines of code

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

all of this is working well everywhere but not on iPhones... someone can help me?

Comment: i too have this issue, and i used the same viewport code. this used to work before, not sure if the latest update of the ios had something to do with that...

Comment: i also tried "user-scalable=0" with no avail.